# Rust structs with nullable Option fields

Tags: rust, option-type

In python, I might have a class that looks like this:

```
class ClientObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = None
        connected = False

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = new Connection('server')
        self.connected = True

    def disconnect(self):
        self.connection.close()
        self.connection = None
        self.connected = False
```

I am trying to do something similar in rust. First off, I question if this is even a good pattern in rust--would you implement a client class with a connection this way? Second, I am getting an error I don't understand with my implementation.

```
pub struct Client {
    seq: int,
    connected: bool,
    socket: Option<UdpSocket>
}

impl Client {

    pub fn connect(&mut self, addr: &SocketAddr) -> ClientConnectionResult {
        match self.socket {
            Some(_) => self.disconnect(),
            None => ()
        };

        self.socket = match UdpSocket::bind(*addr) {
            Ok(s) => Some(s),
            Err(e) => return Err(to_client_error(e))
        };

        self.connected = true;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn disconnect(&mut self) {
        match self.socket {
            None => (),
            Some(s) => drop(s)
        };

        self.socket = None;

        self.connected = false;
    }
}
```

In the disconnect function, the match generates a compile error because it attempts to move the ownership of self.socket. What I want to do is to set self.socket to None and allow it to be later reassigned to something if connect is called. How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be not applicable for your use case, but Rust move semantics and strong typing allow cheap "state machines", when a method consumes `self` (current state) and returns another object which represents another state. That's how [`TcpListener`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/net/tcp/struct.TcpListener.html) is implemented: it has `listen()` method which returns [`TcpAcceptor`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/net/tcp/struct.TcpAcceptor.html), consuming original listener in process. This approach has advantage of typing: you just cannot call methods which does not make sense when the object is in invalid state.

In your case it could look like this:

```rust
use std::kinds::markers::NoCopy;

pub struct DisconnectedClient {
    seq: int,
    _no_copy: NoCopy
}

impl DisconnectedClient {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(seq: int) -> DisconnectedClient {
        DisconnectedClient { seq: seq, _no_copy: NoCopy }
    }

    // DisconnectedClient does not implement Copy due to NoCopy marker so you need 
    // to return it back in case of error, together with that error, otherwise 
    // it is consumed and can't be used again.
    pub fn connect(self, addr: &SocketAddr) -> Result<ConnectedClient, (DisconnectedClient, IoError)> {
        match UdpSocket::bind(*addr) {
            Ok(s) => Ok(ConnectedClient { seq: self.seq, socket: s }),
            Err(e) => Err((self, e))
        }
    }
}

pub struct ConnectedClient {
    seq: int,
    socket: UdpSocket
}

impl ConnectedClient {
    #[inline]
    pub fn disconnect(self) -> DisconnectedClient {
        // self.socket will be dropped here
        DisconnectedClient::new(self.seq)
    }

    // all operations on active connection are defined here
}
```

You first create `DisconnectedClient` using `DisconnectedClient::new()` method. Then, when you want to connect to something, you use `connect()` method, which consumes `DisconnectedClient` and returns new object, `ConnectedClient`, which represents an established connection. When you finished working with this connection, `disconnect()` method turns `ConnectedClient` back to `DisconnectedClient`.

This approach may be more complex, but it has advantage of static checks for incorrect state. You don't have to have `connected()`-like methods; if your variable is of type `ConnectedClient`, then you already know it is connected.

Comment: Hmm, this pattern makes a lot of sense to me. I will probably go this direction.

As for it being applicable or not, this is a learning exercise for me, so it's all applicable.

Answer (score 3):

If in your Python code `self.connected` is equivalent to `self.connection is not None`, then the boolean is a *complete* waste of time and space; you’d be best omitting it or if it is valuable having it as a property:

```
@property
def connected(self):
    return self.connection is not None
```

Similarly in Rust you can go storing the boolean separately, but there is absolutely no point.

```
impl Client {
    pub fn connect(&mut self, addr: &SocketAddr) -> ClientConnectionResult {
        self.disconnect();
        self.socket = Some(try!(UdpSocket::bind(*addr)));
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn disconnect(&mut self) {
        self.socket = None;
    }
}
```

As far as the moving `self.socket` part is concerned, you can’t really do it the way you’ve done it there, because it *is* moving it. You must put something in its place. This can be achieved with something like [`.take()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/type.Option.html#method.take).

`drop` is unnecessary; destructors are called when the value goes out of scope or is otherwise replaced, which `self.socket = None` will cause to happen. Similarly, because `disconnect()` works fine if `socket` is already `None` there is no need for an `if self.socket.is_some()` check (or equivalent pattern matching) around the call of `self.disconnect()` in `connect`.

If you want someone to be able to check whether it’s connected, make a simple method for it:

```
    pub fn connected(&self) -> bool {
        self.socket.is_some()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out drop was unnecessary and for pointing me in the direction of take, which is new to me.